# Navigation Button Not Opening Dialog On Click

Tags: android, toolbar, android-alertdialog

So I am trying to open a Dialog from the navigation button of my Toolbar but it does not open and instead just returns true.

**Here's my navigation on click code:**

```
toolbar_main.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Main.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                DialogNewAmount dialog = new DialogNewAmount();
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");

            }});

    }
});
```

I think the error might be occurring while inflating the dialog

**DialogNewAmount class:**

```
public class DialogNewAmount extends DialogFragment {

private MyDatabase database;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    database = MyDatabase.getDatabase(getActivity());
    database.isOpen();

    //Creating dialog windows using AlertDialog with the name "builder"
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    //Giving reference to the layout for this dialog then displaying it
    final View dialogView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_amount, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    //Getting reference to widgets being displayed in layout
    final EditText editA = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editAmount);
    final EditText editD = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editDescription);

    //Labelling the dialog window
    builder.setTitle("ADD AMOUNT");

    //Handle the cancel button
    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });

    //Handle the Add button

    builder.setPositiveButton("ADD",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {

            String Amount = editA.getText().toString();
            String Description = editD.getText().toString();

            if (Amount.matches("") || (Description.matches(""))) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You can't leave any field blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                try {

                    // Preparing variables
                    int parsedAmount = Integer.parseInt(editA.getText().toString());
                    String myString = editD.getText().toString();

                    //Adding transaction in database
                    database.transactionDAO().addTransaction
                            (new Database.Transaction(parsedAmount, myString));

                    Log.i("Database", "OK");

                    // Create a new transaction
                    Transaction newTransaction = new Transaction(parsedAmount, myString);

                    //Pass new transaction back to main activity
                    Main.createNewTransaction(newTransaction);

                   getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            updateTotalAmount();
                        }});

                    //Quit the dialog
                    dismiss();

                    Log.i("DialogNewAmount", "OK");
                } catch (Error e) {

                    Log.e("DialogNewAmount", "Fail", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }); return builder.create();
}
```

Should I post my logCat as well?

*Any sort of guidance would be highly appreciated!*

Comment: Where is your `DialogNewAmount` class ?

Comment: Now added `DialogNewAmount` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it!

The problem was occurring because I had called the `onClickListener` method before I set the toolbar as support action bar that's why it never gave any fatal errors in the `logCat` as it was all because of I had all the methods messed up.

***Still appreciate the help though!***

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**EDIT**
Initialize dialog in your activity.

```
DialogFragment dialog;


toolbar_main.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Main.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    dialog = (DialogFragment)
                            dialog.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), DialogNewAmount.class.getName());
                    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");

                }});

        }
    });
```

Comment: Variable `dialog` might not have been initialized.

Comment: Cannot recognize method `getActivity()`

Comment: use `getApplicationContext` instead of `getActivity`